# monotouch nsattributedstring style/attribute testing

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, nsattributedstring

I have a NSAttributedString in a UITextView, with  text having multiple attributes (bold/italic etc..)

I am trying to detect which style is applied to the selected portion of the text to enable or disable the various buttons:

```cs
NSRange selectionRange = GetSelectedTextRange();
NSMutableAttributedString text = new NSMutableAttributedString(ActiveTextInput.AttributedText);
NSDictionary attributesDictionary = text.GetAttributes(selectionRange.Location, out selectionRange);

text.EnumerateAttributes(selectionRange, NSAttributedStringEnumeration.LongestEffectiveRangeNotRequired, (NSDictionary attributes, NSRange range, ref bool stop) =>
{
    if (attributes.ObjectForKey(CTStringAttributeKey.UnderlineStyle).Equals(NSUnderlineStyle.Single))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("UNDERLINED");
        stop = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("NON UNDERLINED");
    }
});


protected NSRange GetSelectedTextRange()
{
    NSRange selectionRange = new NSRange(
        ActiveTextInput.GetOffsetFromPosition(ActiveTextInput.BeginningOfDocument, ActiveTextInput.SelectedTextRange.start),
        ActiveTextInput.GetOffsetFromPosition(ActiveTextInput.SelectedTextRange.start, ActiveTextInput.SelectedTextRange.end)
    );

    // if selected range is empty, include the character next to the selector in the current range
    if (selectionRange.Length.Equals(0))
        selectionRange = new NSRange(selectionRange.Location - 1, 1);

    return selectionRange;
}
```

the code raise an exception on the IF line: `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` .

Is this the right way to test for attribute presence ? Moreover, how can I test whether my text is bold or underlined, as they are a single attribute (`CTStringAttributeKey.Font`), I've check some examples ([NSAttributedString Color Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750860/nsattributedstring-color-test)) but color is different as it have its own attribute key.

What I'm trying to achieve it's a rich text editor with simple markup, as Word does with B/U/I/Color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a basic c# problem I guess, when trying to access `<Dictionary>.ObjectForKey()` method, if the key isn't set in the dictionary a NullReference exception is thrown, so just use a `<Dictionary>.TryGetValue()` before trying to access the data by it's keyname